# Chained && and || operators in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, logical-operators

I want to execute a series of commands in a bash script.

If any fail, the script should `echo` a line describing which line failed, and then exit the function.

Currently, my script echos the output adequately, but doesn't exit the script (because the `echo` command returns `0`).

I have

```
COMMAND_A || echo "command A failed" | tee -a $SUMMARY_FILE
COMMAND_B || echo "command B failed" | tee -a $SUMMARY_FILE
COMMAND_C || echo "command C failed" | tee -a $SUMMARY_FILE
```

but these have no dependence on the previous line - I think enclosing with `bash -e` would also not help, since then either `COMMAND_A` failing would exit without the `echo`, or else the `echo` would succeed and nothing would exit.

Since the `echo` will succeed, I can't just add `&&` to each line.

I could perhaps use

```
{ COMMAND_A && \ 
     { COMMAND_B && \
          { COMMAND_C || echo "C failed" | tee -a $SUM } \ 
     || echo "B failed" | tee -a $SUM }  \
|| echo "A failed" | tee -a $SUM }
```

but this seems very clunky.

Is there a better syntax/style/method?

For a concrete example:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. || \
            echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): cmake failed for $1" | tee -a $SUMFILE
        make -j16 || \
            echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): make failed for $1" | tee -a $SUMFILE
        sudo make install && \
            echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): Installed $1" | tee -a $SUMFILE || \
            echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): make install failed for $1" | tee -a $SUMFILE
```

**Edit**

I can perhaps get some improvement with

```
COMMAND_A || { echo "A failed" && false; } && \
COMMAND_B || { echo "B failed" && false; } && \
COMMAND_C && echo "C succeeded" || { echo "C failed" && false; }
```

but this will still print that `A`, `B` and `C` failed if `A` fails (even though the commands are short-circuited, hence the improvement)

Answer (score 0):

Since the series of commands is executed within a function, the `return` statement can be used.

If this were not the case, `exit` may be the appropriate choice.

Consequently, I can use the idea in the question's edit to write:

```
standardInstall() {
# Should be passed the directory (ie application/library) name as
# an argument.
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "No argument was passed to standardInstall()"
        echo "Exiting"
        exit 2
    fi
    pushd $1/build/

    cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$KF5 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. || \
        { echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): cmake failed for $1" \ 
          | tee -a $SUMFILE && return 1; } && \
    make -j16 || \
        { echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): make failed for $1" \ 
          | tee -a $SUMFILE && return 1; } && \
    sudo make install && \
        echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): Installed $1" | tee -a $SUMFILE || \
        { echo "$(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S): make install failed for $1" \ 
          | tee -a $SUMFILE && return 1; }

    popd
}
```