# Chaining OR and AND in Bash

Tags: bash

I would like to chain the OR and AND commands so that I print the contents of a directory to stdout if the directory exists, or in the case that it does not, print a message to stdout saying that the directory "$MY_DIR" is being created and then create it.

I have the following code.

```bash
ls "$MY_DIR" || echo "Creating $MY_DIR" && mkdir -p "$MY_DIR"
```

**Is this the correct and canonical way to do this?** Will `mkdir` always run since `echo` will return `0` return status, even in the case that `ls` does return?

The most relevant question I have located so far is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006797/chained-and-operators-in-bash-scripting) which does not eliminate my doubts.

Comment: This is a [classic bash pitfall](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) so take care.

Comment: @shellter: better to say `[[ -e $MY_DIR ]]` to prevent `mkdir` bouncing off of a non-directory file. It's also unclear whether the user would want the file to be listed if it's not a dir, or for something else to happen.

Comment: @sorpigal: Good point. I took the liberty of editing that into my answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Better `mkdir -p "$MY_DIR" || { printf "error: creating %s\n" "$MY_DIR" >&2; exit 1; }`

Comment: Given that `mkdir` will already have printed a reasonable error message I don't think adding another one will be valuable. How about: `create-and-ls () { mkdir -p "$1" && ls "$1"; }` -- of course, both of these change semantics in that you do not get a "creating directory" message if the dir did not exist to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not do what you are doing that way in any case. You should group your commands for clarity if for no other reason.

```
ls "$MY_DIR" || {
    echo "Creating $MY_DIR"
    mkdir -p "$MY_DIR"
}
```

This has several advantages: your intent is more clearly expressed, there is less ambiguity between what the human thinks will happen and what the computer will do, and it stops relying on the exit code from `echo` that you were not really interested in to begin with. Even if your original version worked entirely correctly it was more vulnerable to later, naïve modification.

A oneliner form is of course possible, if less readable:

```
ls "$MY_DIR" || { echo "Creating $MY_DIR"; mkdir -p "$MY_DIR"; }
```

As for your original method, consider this:

If the `ls` command fails:

```
false || true && echo mkdir # prints mkdir
```

But if the `ls` command *succeeds*

```
true || true && echo mkdir # also prints mkdir
```

Whereas

```
true || { true; echo mkdir; } # does not print
false || { true; echo mkdir; } # prints mkdir
```

It gets worse: I am not entirely clear whether `ls` will set an unsuccessful return code if the file/directory does not exist. It's certainly true that GNU `ls` does this, and it may be common, but the standard [doesn't seem to say](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) what constitutes success or failure, so implementations may well disagree.

Comment: Thanks very much. Upvoted and accepted since this clarified my doubts on how to group commands inside chains.

Answer (score 4):

Why does it have to be chaining, with all the potential problems that might bring? Why not express your intentions clearly?

Also, UPPERCASE is usually reserved for environment variables.

```
# -d checks for directory specifically, use -e for existence.
# Thanks to @sorpigal for pointing it out.
if [[ -d $my_dir ]]
then
    ls "$my_dir"
else
    echo "Creating $my_dir"
    mkdir -p "$my_dir"
fi
```

Or, if it *has* to be one line...

```
if [[ -d $my_dir ]]; then ls "$my_dir"; else echo "Creating $my_dir"; mkdir -p "$my_dir"; fi
```

Comment: Even environment variables that are application-defined rather than system-meaningful should have lowercase names; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html.